# Force and velocity $-$ are they simultaneous?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation

*For some reason this question disappeared, so I am re-asking it.*

I would think yes, because, if a rope tied to a swinging rock breaks, the rock flies off in the direction that is perpendicular to the direction of the last instant of the acceleration. The acceleration which existed at the last instant determined the direction of the velocity of the rock as it flies off.

So, the acceleration over time changes the magnitude of the velocity of a particle and/or it's direction. But at any instant of time, the velocity is determined by the acceleration at that instant.

Is that correct?

Comment: If a truck drives at $v=100km/h$ and the only force acting at time $t$ is a fly, which hits the truck, would you say that the acceleration due to the fly determines the velocity of the truck?

Comment: Also, in classical mechanics we do not consider different "realities". Instead, we assume an absolute space and time. Hence, $v(t)$ and $a(t)$ refer to the same time and are therefore "simultaneous".

Answer (score 1):

No, the velocity at a particular instant of time is not determined by the acceleration at that particular instant of time. Acceleration is the time-derivative of velocity. In other words,

$$\mathbf{a}(t)=\lim_{\Delta t\to0}\frac{\mathbf{v}(t+\Delta t)-\mathbf{v}(t)}{\Delta t}=\frac{d\mathbf{v}(t)}{dt}$$

Thus, while mathematicians are not looking, one is allowed to write $\mathbf{v}(t+dt)=\mathbf{a}(t) dt+\mathbf{v}(t)$. Thus, the velocity at any instant, say $t+dt$, is determined by the velocity at some infinitesimally distant time in the past (i.e., $\mathbf{v}(t)$) and the acceleration $\mathbf{a}(t)$ during that small interval in past $dt$. The variations in the value of acceleration during this infinitesimally small interval of time don't contribute to the first order in $dt$.

**Physical Relevance**

The laws of mechanics tell us that when we apply a force, we induce an acceleration in the object immediately. However, we do not directly induce some desired value of velocity in the object--we only induce a time-rate of change of velocity (i.e., acceleration) and the velocity of the object at later times will change in accordance with this acceleration.

Comment: If the rope broke a short length in time earlier, the rock’s direction would be different. There can be no other explanation than that the acceleration had an instantaneous effect on the rock’s velocity at the last instant it existed.